# Get item of the source model from the index of a QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: qt

I have an application that contains a `QTreeView` whose underlying model, say `MyModel` is derived from a `QStandardItemModel`. In order to filter out from the view some of the items of `MyModel`, I plug it into a `QSortFilterProxyModel` which is in turn plugged into the `QTreeView`. When I need to get one item of my source model from a given index of my proxy model I always have to code this:

```
auto my_model = dynamic_cast<MyModel*>(proxy_model->sourceModel());
auto source_index = proxy_model->mapToSource(proxy_index);
auto item = my_model->itemFromIndex(source_index);
```

I did not find any direct method to do this. Would you be aware of more *direct* way to do this or is that the sign that I imserunderstand something in the way I use Qt proxy model concept ?

Answer (score 5):

You are using it correctly - there is no built in shortcut for the steps you are doing.

You could use `qobject_cast` to speed things up if `MyModel` has the `Q_OBJECT` macro, but otherwise thats exactly how to use the models.

For situation like these, I typically create a wrapper method on the class that is using the models or extend the `QSortFilterProxyModel` to have such a method. YOu could, for example create a `StandardSortFilterProxyModel` that extends the former and only accepts `QStandardItemModel` based classes and provides a bunch of methods to access the items the way you need to.

Note that if you only want to get specific data out of the model instead of the item itself (like the text of the selected column), you can always use `proxy_model->data(proxy_index)` directly and get your value from the QVariant.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. In fact, I need the item directly because I connected my `QTreeView` to a right-click contextual menu into which I have to check the type of the item in order to launch different kind of actions depending on the type of the item.